# iOS/macOS Mail in dark mode inverts SVG mask colors, causing masking behavior to change

Tags: svg, mask, macos-mail-app

I have an SVG image that uses masking to cut out a hole in another shape. I've simplified the complex shapes involved down to this representative example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" fill="#ffffff" />
      <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="32" fill="#000000" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle mask="url(#mask)" cx="128" cy="128" r="64" fill="#ff0000" />
</svg>
```

This works as expected, i.e., draws the following donut shape, in pretty much every context:

[image]

However, if I inline the SVG in an email and view it in macOS Mail (16.0, comes with Monterey 12.3.1) or iOS Mail while dark mode is enabled, I get this peculiar version:

[image]

What appears to be happening is that these two apps are trying to guess at a dark-mode interpretation of the SVG, and have erroneously changed the mask's `#ffffff` to a very dark grey (`#232323`, if I had to guess, which is the background color of the application itself in dark mode) and `#000000` to `#ffffff`, thereby mostly but not entirely inverting the masking behavior.

This seems like a bug in Mail. Is there a way to tell Mail to not mess with the colors defined in the mask? I tried a couple workarounds, but they were insufficient:

- using `prefers-color-scheme` to define the mask's colors so I can "pre-invert" it for dark mode, which works here but breaks the image in every *other* context
- obscuring the mask coloration enough that it won't try to invert it (e.g. by using `linear-gradient(#ffffff,#ffffff)` instead of just `#ffffff`), which just breaks the images everywhere

Comment: You could try to set [`mask-type: alpha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-type) on the `<mask>` element and use opacity values instead of colors to describe the mask. (There is also [`mask-mode: alpha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-mode), to be applied on the target masked element, but that can work at best for Safari >= 15.4.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working off of ccprog's suggestion, I got this SVG to work as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" mask-type="alpha">
      <path
        d="
          M 0 0
          L 256 0
          L 256 256
          L 0 256
          L 0 0
          M 128 96
          a 32 32 180 1 1 0 64
          a 32 32 180 1 1 0 -64
          z
        "
        fill-rule="evenodd"
      />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle mask="url(#mask)" cx="128" cy="128" r="64" fill="#ff0000" />
</svg>
```

In addition to the switch to `mask-type` (so that we are masking using something that iOS/macOS Mail won't try to invert), the mask had to be redefined. In particular, it had to fill in everywhere that *isn't* in the circle, using `fill-rule="evenodd"` to get it to fill in the desired areas. I couldn't just switch the existing shapes to use opacity, because the `circle` would be want to be opacity 0 (in order to specify that the circle should be cut out) and the `rect` would come through behind it with opacity 1, making the mask a no-op.

The new mask path, if rendered in black against a white background, looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also simplify your svg by using a **compound path.**

The "cut out" area is defined by a sub path with an opposite path direction.

In your case:

```
// outer circle - clockwise
M 128 64
a 64 64 0 0 1 0 128
a 64 64 0 0 1 0 -128
z

// innercircle - counter clockwise
M 128 96
a 32 32 180 1 0 0 64
a 32 32 180 1 0 0 -64
z
```

You could also do it the other way round: counterclockwise for outer shape, clockwise for the inner ones.

```css
body{
background:#222
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">
 <path
d="
M 128 64
a 64 64 0 0 1 0 128
a 64 64 0 0 1 0 -128
z
M 128 96
a 32 32 180 1 0 0 64
a 32 32 180 1 0 0 -64
z"
fill="#ff0000" />
</svg>
```

This way you don't need any additional `fill-rule` - even less capable applications like image viewers can render these svgs flawlessly.
This concept (clipping by alternating path directions) is actually around since the very first Bézier drawing technologies (e.g post-script).

You can create compound paths in every vector editor (e.g. Adobe illustrator, inkscape etc) by applying a path operation like subtract/extract.

Further reading: [The Winding Order of the Fill Rule](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch06-fill-rule.html)

Comment: This is a good technique to know! I ended up selecting my self-answer since the solution there is more broadly applicable/a more direct fix; in the real problem I had that this was simplified from, a compound path dependent on winding order is not a straightforward change.